# Column Does Not Belong To Table Error in VB .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

Fairly new to .Net here and having trouble with a line of code. I have a routine in a custom class that is assigning values to an object based on data from a table row. However, several tables may be used to update these values and only have some of the fields in common. Therefore, I want to check each field value to make sure it exists before I attempt to access it's value to assign to my object. However, I am getting the error "Column x Does Not Belong To Table." Any suggestions as to how I might be able to accomplish this without throwing an error?

```
        'error occurs on first line
        If Not memberRow.Item("nickname") Is Nothing Then
            returnval.NickName = Trim(memberRow.Item("nickname").ToString)
        End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column doesn't exist, the [Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/146h6tk5.aspx) method will throw an exception.

Probably the easiest solution is:

```
Dim wIndex As Integer

wIndex = memberRow.Table.Columns.IndexOf("nickname")
If wIndex <> -1 Then
   returnval.NickName = Trim(memberRow.Item(wIndex).ToString)
Else
   returnval.NickName = String.Empty
End IF
```

Comment: This doesn't work because I am using a DataRow and not a DataSet and there doesn't appear to be an equivalent property of a DataRow to check in this manner.

Comment: Sorry, had a slight typo in the answer: it should be memberRow.Table not .Tables.

Comment: FYI - what I actually did was take the original format and changed it to

If memberRow.Table.Columns.IndexOf("nickname") <> -1 Then

Answer (score 1):

Assuming  `memberRow` is of type `System.Data.DataRow` you will want to look at the table definition.  Something like :

```
If ( memberRow.Table.Columns.Contains("nickname")) Then
   If Not memberRow.Item("nickname") Is Nothing Then
            returnval.NickName = Trim(memberRow.Item("nickname").ToString)
        End If
End If
```

You can also do as @competent_tech suggests and trap for exceptions, but that depends on which side of the [slow/not-slow exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161942/how-slow-are-net-exceptions) debate you fall on.