# Why is throwing exceptions so slow?

Tags: .net, performance, exception, internals

They are telling us not to use exceptions to control flow of our programs because throwing exceptions is slow. I have never heard any explanation why is throwing exceptions so slow.

So the question is:

> What is the mechanism of throwing exceptions and what are particular operations involved which may have performance impact?

EDIT:

Some clarification: I would like to hear what extra work is need by operation system to handle throwing exceptions. Is there some switching between user and kernel mode which are that costly? Or maybe constructing exception object is costly? Or maybe there is something with switching program flow what I am missing? My question is programming language agnostic (I hope so, but prove me wrong). However If you need some anchor then I am interest the most in .NET internals related with this topic.

EDIT2:

I don't have any issues with exceptions performance. I just would like to understand internals of this mechanism.

EDIT3:

Made my question more clear.

Comment: Which implementation of which language are you referring to, and who's saying its exception handling is slow?

Comment: I am referring to throwing exceptions in general and I guess everyone is saying that: my academic teachers, my colleagues, my boss, everyone on the Internet :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How slow are .NET exceptions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161942/how-slow-are-net-exceptions)

Comment: If you have performance problems due to exceptions, it isn't just that the exception is slow, it is that you're throwing *way* too many of them. In other words, if you're using exceptions correctly, to indicate *exceptional problems*, then you shouldn't have to bother.

Comment: A common saying is:  If you care about exception performance you're probably overusing exceptions.  However performance is still a good discussion.

Comment: I don't have performance issues and I do now or I can measure exception impact, I would like to how how exceptions work underneath in operation system. There is no single answer to this question on SO, or I am unable to find such information.

Comment: They aren't slow - but there's other reasons to not use exceptions for flow control.  See additional answers.

Comment: If you want to know how they work, you should just go and create a new question for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Exception handling requires some complexity and "magic".  Seconding @Joni's response a major cost is gathering the stack trace.  When an exception is thrown, the run time has to walk down the stack's activation records looking for a compatible exception handler, executing finally blocks each step of the way.  All this has to occur at run time; it can't be fixed up by the compiler.  In languages like C++ destructors have to be executed.

Exception processing is essentially an out of band "exceptional" processing mode.  Things that speed up normal execution such as caching don't work as well.  (I would imagine locality-of-reference is a lot worse here).  This processing could be optimized, but since exc handing is supposed to be "special" it's given less attention.

Comment: Finally blocks and destructors don't contribute to the overhead of throwing an exception anymore than using return values and manually making your way up the callstack. These finally blocks and destructors will execute regardless.

Answer (score 4):

Exceptions are created in the application level; there is no operating system support for them. There is no particular reason why throwing and catching an exception should be slower than any other nonlocal transfer of control, like calling or returning from a function.

What makes exceptions "slower" than the alternative of returning error codes depends on the extra work required by the particulars of the programming environment. In Java for example the slowest part of throwing an exception is filling in the stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason it's a bad idea to use exceptions for flow control is I should be able to attach a debugger and tell it to break on exceptions ... and it breaks in EXCEPTIONAL CASES.  If the code is using exceptions for flow control and it breaks constantly under normal operation it becomes really hard to debug with out conditioning out exceptions etc... but then maybe you end up missing a real exceptional case.

If I write tests validating positive functionality, I should be able to run them with a debugger attached and it doesn't catch.  If you can't do that, you might be abusing exceptions.

An example: let's say I have code to get an item by id.  My code conclusively finds that an item by that id does not exist.  Should I throw NotFoundException?  This is a point of contention - I would say no - nothing exceptional/error happened here.  Your code correctly found out nothing by that id existed and no errors finding that out occurred.  these are cases where I see exceptions being abused and leads to exceptions getting thrown in non-excpetional cases.

Answer (score 2):

You have been misinformed, but the outcome on your actual code probably won't change either way. The exception handling system in .NET is actually quite fast, meaning its performance is comparable to you other options for error handling. However, like mentioned in another answer, you only want to use exceptions appropriately - i.e. only for exceptional situations which you *do not expect to occur* during a normal run of your application. The reasons for this are as follows:

- Analyzing code flow involving exceptions is more complicated than code not involving exceptions, so your "normal" code should avoid throwing exceptions.
- The Visual Studio debugger will report every time an exception is thrown. It's only one line in the output window, but if you are misusing exceptions then this wonderful feature will quickly turn into a nightmare.
- Visual Studio has the ability to break when a particular type of exception is thrown. If you consistently use exceptions correctly (for their intended purpose, and only for indicating an actual exception of that type), this feature provides a way to quickly debug errors in your application related to error handling (recovery, reporting, etc.).

When it comes to handling actual exceptional situations, exception handling actually provides a performance benefit over other things like returning error codes. When it comes to branch prediction and hinting, the JIT can make the assumption that code will *never* throw an exception, allowing it to generate code that effectively uses any available branch prediction features of your processor to avoid branching overhead for code that includes error handling features but is not actively handling an error.