# How To Avoid Try And Catch Statements

Tags: c#

```
//Example 2 - Validate Date for the format MM/DD/YYYY 
private bool ValidateDate(string stringDateValue)
{
   try
   {
       CultureInfo CultureInfoDateCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
       DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(stringDateValue, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfoDateCulture);
       return true;
   }
   catch
   {
       return false;
   }
 }
```

---

How to set this code working without using the try and catch?

Comment: Why do you want that?

Comment: what is the issue of using it ? or why do you want to bypass?

Comment: First of all, why do you want to avoid try catch block ??

Comment: Feel free to correct me if I am wrong, but I believe TryParseExact fails faster than throwing an exception would. I believe OP wishes to avoid the delay associated with exception handling. I know it is only very slight but over a large batch it might be important.

Comment: Also See: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161942/how-slow-are-net-exceptions

Comment: It also goes against best practice, in most any language/framework, to manage control flow with exception handling that isn't really handling exceptions.

Answer (score 9):

Use [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx):

```
private bool ValidateDate(string stringDateValue)
{
    DateTime dummy;
    CultureInfo CultureInfoDateCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    return DateTime.TryParseExact(stringDateValue, "MM/dd/yyyy",
                                  CultureInfoDateCulture, DateTimeStyles.None,
                                  out dummy);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) instead, which will let you control flow with a conditional `if`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
CultureInfo CultureInfoDateCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
DateTime date;

bool works = DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfoDateCulture , 
                       DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the simpliest way is:

```
    private static bool ValidateDate(string stringDateValue)
    {
        DateTime dummy;
        return DateTime.TryParseExact(stringDateValue, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None,  out dummy);
    }
```