# Too many exceptions for the circuit breaker?

Tags: c#, circuit-breaker

I was just reading some answers to this question about [slow exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161942/how-slow-are-net-exceptions). I completely agree with the idea that exceptions can and should used instead of return codes despite of each being considerably slower (although not necessarily noticeable).

I have implemented a circuit breaker in a service that connects to an 3rd party that is called several times on every page request. In the case of a failure, this means that many exceptions are going to be thrown (and logs will be filled as well).

Would this ever be a problem?

Comment: Now compare how long it takes to perform a request to a 3rd party service with footprint that brings a thrown exception.

Comment: And think about how much you care about a bit of performance loss if everything is broken already...

Comment: @zerkms, that was exactly the problem. We were getting throttled requests from time to time that made the site awfully slow! What we have now is so much better.

Comment: @JonSkeet (I'm honoured), yes, good point. The conclusion I take from your thought suggestion is we care about throwing too many exceptions but here it's an acceptable issue considering the alternative.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts guys. I'd say those comments were answers (even though short). I cannot accept comments.

Comment: I don't think any of the comments are really answers, but really because the question isn't concrete enough *to* answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I think it's a question about my concrete doubt. No sure how many would have this doubt and look for it here though. If people vote to delete, I'll end up deleting it. Thanks!

Comment: We all will share your doubts once we image our lives being on the line with a circuit breaker that delays for raising lengthy exceptions.. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it, the circuit breaker is fine the one it is. Someone else (not here) suggested to implement the circuit breaker without raising exceptions as not to log a lot of stuff. That doesn't seem right to me and I haven't been able to think of a nice way of doing that generically as I need the circuit breaker to be used in more than one service (currently 2 - the methods being intercepted by Unity).

The only change I decided to do to my application was to cache the result of the method that calls the 3rd parties. There is no down-side as far as I could see because the data is not changed frequently and we can afford it to be stale.