# i want to improve this Powershell Command?

Tags: powershell

some times after i copy a folder to onother drive i like to md5 hash compare to make sure they are identical i use the command bellow i run it on the source then on the copy

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "source" -Recurse -File |

Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 |

Export-Csv -Path 'new source\MediaHashes1.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

what i want to improve is

i want powershell to hash md5 check the 2 folders compare the results and then tell me if they are identical or not in a single command

Comment: What you propose is not robust.  There is a small probability that two items that was not identical will give same hash.   So without comparing actual files your code may not work.

Comment: @jdweng Although technically correct, I don't think that's useful to try and take into account here. `Get-FileHash` defaults to SHA256, the likelihood of a collision occurring is literally 1 in a trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillions (to my knowledge no known collisions have been identified yet)

Comment: Related: [Powershell Speed: How to speed up ForEach-Object MD5/hash check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59916692/1701026)

Comment: why not use Robocopy /mir ?