# Comparing the hash of a file, containing a list of hashes of multiple files instead of each file, is it good?

Tags: powershell, hash, checksum

I am writing a Powershell script that accepts a list of files, compresses them in an archive, and then decompresses it to another path.I intend to check if the final extracted files are identical to the input files.

So I started writing a function that calculates the hashes of all files from input, writes them in a CSV file as (Relative Path, Hash) named `InputHashes.csv`, then does the same for the extracted files and writes them into a separate CSV file named `OutputHashes.csv`.

By Relative path I mean, if the input path is `C:\Files\Data` and there is a file with a full path `C:\Files\Data\Tests\image.png`, The relative path will be the full path, without the input path `\Tests\image.png`, same for the output files and this makes the paths identical and comparable.

Now I wanted to write the function that cycles each file from the output, checks the relative path in `InputHashes.csv` and compare the hashes to detect if the output is not the same as the input.

But before that, an idea came into my mind, "Why not just compare the hash of the two `InputHashes.csv` and `OutputHashes.csv` file instead of comparing each file one by one?"

Is this a good practice?

My current files list is nearly 8170 and 1.8 GB in size, but it will grow in size and numbers soon.

Comment: I don't want to know which file is tampered or damaged, I just want to know if there is a mismatch in the whole or not.

Comment: If you re-compute the hashes for each file on extraction, make sure you use the same delimiters, whitespace, and line endings, use the same character encoding, and list them in the same order, then it should be fine to just compare the hashes of the csv files.

Comment: Make sure you use a cryptographic hash with collision resistance like sha256 to avoid criticism. Not md4, md5, sha1, rmd160.

Comment: I would compare the file length first before getting into the expensive hashing method, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59916692/1701026

Comment: @SimonGoater Thanks for the reply, yes there is one hashing function and it handles both the input and output files, so the results should be completely identical. Also, the default algorithm for the Get-FileHash function is SHA256, which I'm using.

Comment: @iRon Thanks for the reply, the main reason for me to implement a verification function was I had an incident that with a particular algorithm, the output was the same(modified dates, attributes, sizes, etc...) but I could not open any file, and I checked the hashes and all were different. i suspect damaged or the algorithm cheated to just show itself as superior in compression while actually, it was destroying the data in the process. not sure yet.