# Can't return Ok() , Unauthorized(), BadRequest() in repository c# .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I implemented an `IUserRepository`, where I implement login and registration in my `UserRepository`; this is my code

```
public async Task<IActionResult> LoginAsync([FromBody] UserCred user)
{
    var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.username, user.password, user.rememberMe, false);

    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        var token = _jwtAuthenticationManager.Authenticate(user.username, user.password);
        if (token == null)
            return Unauthorized();
        return Ok(token);
    }
    return BadRequest();
}
```

However, I'm getting an error of:

> The name "BadRequest" does not exist in the current context

Same for the `Ok` and `Unauthorized`.

However, I did not have this issue when I was implementing these calls directly in my `userController`. I suppose I can only return `BadRequest` in the controller? Is there any way I can overcome this since, if it's not `IActionResult`, how will I check if `results.Succeeded`?

Moreover, this is my `UserController`:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] UserCred user)
{
   return await _userRepository.LoginAsync(user);
}
```

Comment: You should not return Action Results from your repository, but some sort of Sign in Result with a token or error message to indicate success.

Comment: Controllers and repositories are not the same thing. Controllers handle HTTP endpoints, the repository is the unit of work for data persistence.

Comment: I thought so too, however if its not IActionResult how will i check if results.Succeeded?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`BadRequest()` is a method of the controller itself.

It's better to return a value from `IUserRepository`, e.g. null or token, and then in the controller map that value to `Ok` or `BadRequest` response. 
Making a decision about the response type is the responsibility of the controller itself.
Code like this placed in the controller should do the job:

```
token = await _userRepository.LoginAsync(user);
return token == null ? BadRequest() : Ok(token);
```

Comment: Worked after making my my repo as Task<String> and doing what u said. Thanks!

Comment: I was having a similar issue and didn't realize why. This answer helped me notice that my controller was not inheriting from `ControllerBase` as it should have been. The compiler error isn't too helpful in this case.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible by returning EG.

```
new BadRequestObjectResult("some error");
```

**But, you shouldn't be doing anything web related in a repository!**

Instead you should throw an appropriate exception from your repository and catch it in the controller. Then, when you catch the exception, return BadRequest from there.

Also, be sure you are returning the correct response.

BadRequest means there was something wrong with the request - maybe the username or password was null, etc. This should be checked before even attempting to hit the repository.

Unauthorized may be a better response if authentication fails.

Then, if there is genuinely an error, don't hide it, it will cause problems later when you have lots of endpoints you can't debug, return a 500 response (but don't include the exception details in production)

Comment: Not my downvote, but really I would use exceptions only if there is not other way to communicate with the calling code and the situation is so desperately broken that there is no way out. Instead a boolean value or if you need to return more information even a custom MyAppResult class is a better choice.

Comment: I strongly disagree. If the issue is bad enough to return BadRequest, then there is exceptional behavior, so an exception is correct. Too many people avoid and even hide exceptions through overzealous handling, leading to overcomplicated and difficult to maintain code. Use exceptions properly!

Comment: I'm afraid @Steve is 100% right here, throwing exceptions should be only done in exceptional circumstances. It is expensive and can easily destroy the performance of a server under load.

Comment: Of course there are many ways to skin a cat. I don't believe exceptions are as costly as you're suggesting.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161942/how-slow-are-net-exceptions

Comment: Actually the Exception -> Response behavior is already baked into Asp.Net. Look up the ExceptionHandling Middleware. It makes especially sense if you need to return more then a StatusCode but info in the body(ProblemDetails as its called in Asp.Net). The system does it that way why shouldn't I?

Comment: To quote Jon Skeet in his answer there: "You've missed the point of the answer. Obviously throwing an exception is much slower than returning a normal value" and "Basically, exceptions shouldn't happen often unless you've got significant correctness issues"

Comment: @Ralf Again, those exceptions are exceptional and not used for determining app control flow. That middleware exists to deal with unhandled exceptions.